# Spring Webservice client returns no data

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

To consume a webservice in our Spring webapplication I follow this instructions: [Calling web service with JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean](https://www.ralfebert.de/archive/java/campaign_monitor_java_spring/)

I have generate the client classes with wsimport and I can use this classes in a command line client. All works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrderServiceRequest req = new OrderServiceRequest()
    // set fields 
    req.setLoginId('test');
    ProfileService profileService = new ProfileService();
    ProfileSoap port = profileService.getProfileSoap12();
    OrderServiceResponse response = port.orderServiceRequest(req);
    System.out.println("ErrorCode=" + response.getErrorCode());
}
```

I implement a service in Spring with the generated classes.
I configure the service as Spring Bean:

```
<bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
             <property name="serviceInterface" value="my.package.name.ProfileSoap" />           
             <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://localhost:9999/connector/MyWebService?wsdl" />            
             <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://url.to.namespace" />
            <property name="serviceName" value="ProfileService" />
            <property name="endpointAddress" value="http://localhost:9999/connector/MyWebService" />
    </bean>
```

In another Service I inject the Service and call the webservice:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myService")
ProfileSoap myService;

OrderServiceRequest req = new OrderServiceRequest();
req.setLoginId("12345");
req.setPassword("test");
req.setEAN("9783864905254");
// Request
OrderServiceResponse response = myService.orderServiceRequest(req);
// all fields of the response are null!
System.out.println(response.getErrorCode());
```

With the TCP-Monitor in Eclipse I can see that the response returns the correct data, but my Response-Object in the service has no data.

What approach should I take to debug this problem? Any help appreciated